# Maxima For Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, maxima

I am trying to write a loop in maxima that will iterate i through values of 1 to 21, for each individual value of i the variable j is is iterated through values of 1 to 21. At every value of j the two are compared against each other and if i

```
for i:1 while i<=21 do(for j:1 while j<=21  do 
(if i<j then aa:realpart(c1[-j+i+21]))) and do aa1:makelist(aa,i,1,21,1);
```

Nothing even shows up on wxmaxima, it acts like it does not see this part of the code.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry the first paragraph got cut off it should read
"I am trying to write a loop in maxima that will iterate i through values of 1 to 21, for each individual value of i the variable j is is iterated through values of 1 to 21. At every value of j the two are compared against each other and if i<j then it pulls a value from an array c1 and assigns it to aa. I then want to make another array aa1 from values of aa.

Comment: As far as I understand makelist takes four arguments, so makelist(aa,i,1,21,1) should produce error.

Comment: It would be better to clarify what you are trying to do at large, because it is a strange code. Why you are trying to fill up array aa1 multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

Someone just asked a rather similar [question](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/41113) on the Maxima mailing list, following up on their [previous](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/41076) one from two days before.

Now, terribly nice chap called Rupert Swarbrick replied constructively to both of those questions. He's **so** nice that he'll reply (yet) again. What it looks like you're trying to do is make a matrix, `aa`, such that `aa[i,j]` is zero on or below the diagonal and is equal to `c1[-j+i+21]` above the diagonal. Assuming that's the case, try the following:

```
genmatrix (lambda ([i,j], if i<j then realpart(c1[-j+i+21]) else 0), 21);
```

If you want something else, you'll have to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your code:

```
for i:1 while i<=21 do(for j:1 while j<=21  do 
(if i<j then aa:realpart(c1[-j+i+21]))) and do aa1:makelist(aa,i,1,21,1);
```

Formatting this a little more clearly, it is:

```
for i:1 while i<=21 do
   (for j:1 while j<= 21 do
       (if i<j then aa:realpart(c1[-j+i+21])
       )
   ) 
and 
do aa1:makelist(aa,i,1,21,1);
```

Well, "and" is a boolean operator, and applying it to two loops isn't terribly meaningful (unless the loops return booleans), though Maxima lets you write it.  Instead of (a and b) or (a and do b), you probably wanted to write (a,b), which executes a then b.

The nesting is probably not what you intended, either.

The second loop is "do aa1:...".  In Maxima, "do xxx" is equivalent to "while true do xxx", i.e. an infinite loop. That would explain why this code never returned.

By the way, a simpler way of writing "for i:1 while i<=21 do..." is "for i thru 21 do...".

Hope this helps.

```
   -s
```